# Is a square with a diagonal drawn connecting two corners still considered a square?

Tags: geometry

Is a square with a diagonal drawn connecting two corners still considered a square?
This is a question about the definition of a square.

Comment: I would say it's a *dissected* square...

Comment: Yes, but why are you asking? Is this yet another item where you were marked wrong by your instructor and you want us to say you were right?

Comment: Is a person wearing only a hat nude? Depends on what one is concentrating on.

Answer (score 1):

No, a square is a 4 sided polygon, with all sides equal, and all interior angles 90 degrees.

A square with a line across the corners is not a 4 sided polygon. Hence not a square.

Comment: i.e. the square is the quadrilateral that is both a rectangle and a rhombus.

Comment: I don't think that drawing a diagonal can _remove_ the innate squareness of the shape that was already on the paper before the diagonal was drawn. The square is still a square -- it is just not the only thing on the paper anymore.

Comment: I tend to agree with Henning and Andre but I asked the question because it arose in a square counting puzzle and now I wonder whether the definition is as William suggests.